# background image and background color width difference

Tags: css

I have a few modules set up with background colors and background images but they are not the same widths for some reason. The approach is to create sections like a product page that scrolls down, so it is pretty much 1 column. I am not sure why but the right side extends further on some than others. [This is where two modules meet, but the blue one is too short.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eAyw.png) Is there a way to get them the same, or is there a better way to scale with the browser? [This is the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTM60.png)

```
#module1 {
    background-color: rgb( 255, 193, 187);
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#module2 {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#module4 {
    background: url(../images/gallery-1024.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 800px;
    margin-top: 23.24px;
}
```

Comment: What was your approach to achieve the desirable result *(will be great you edit your post with that)*? Did you get any error in the process?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I included more info, thanks!

Comment: *Good! What does your HTML looks like?*

Comment: *Any link to your actual background image online?*

Comment: Please post your HTML code as code, not as an image. We're not going to bother typing it all out ourselves. `:-)`